# Android:Is it possible to restrict voice recognition to single user?

Tags: android

I am new to android development. I am trying to develop a app which able to recognize the voice and take action only if input voice is of a specific person. Is is possible to in android?If Yes which android services I need to use and how?

Answer (score 1):

Practically, this is an insanely difficult thing to do. Voice signals are sharp and chaotic and being able to recognize words is a feat in itself.

If you want to get into it you can always start with the android systems built in api: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html

Comment: Agreed this is difficult to do.